# I can't map my "about page view" in my application urls.py

Tags: python, django, django-views, django-urls

I can not map my "about page view" in my application urls.py file.
I tried to find solutions on the internet but I could not. Reinstalled django, created again new project but the same error appers.

The error is: `SyntaxError`.

I do not know where I have made mistake. Note that I want to map application urls.py in another file. Then join application urls.py file to the project's.

*My python version is*  **2.7**

*My django version is*  **1.8**

This is my **views.py** file.

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse


def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Rango says hello world! <a href='/rango/about'> 
    About </a>")

def about(request):
    return HttpResponse("Rango Says: Here is the about page <a 
    href='/rango/'> Index </a>")
```

This is my **application urls.py** file.

```
from django.conf.urls import patterns, url
from rango import views


urlpatterns = patterns('',
        url(r'^$', views.index, name='index')
        urlr('^rango/about', views.about, name='about'))
```

This is my **project urls.py** file.

```
from django.conf.urls import include, url
from django.contrib import admin

urlpatterns = [
   # Examples:
   # url(r'^$', 'projectX.views.home', name='home'),
   # url(r'^blog/', include('blog.urls')),

  url(r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
  url(r'^rango/', include("rango.urls"))
]
```

Answer (score 0):

You have two typos. Firstly, you are missing commas after the `url()` instances (it is required for the first one, strongly recommended for the second). Secondly, you have `urlr` instead of url for the second pattern. It should be:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^rango/about', views.about, name='about'),
)
```

As a further improvement, you should change `urlpatterns` to a list instead of using `patterns()`, and add the `$` to the end of the regex for the about page.

```
urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
    url(r'^rango/about/$', views.about, name='about'),
]
```

You also have a problem in your views. Strings with double quotes should not have newlines. You should either have,

```
def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Rango says hello world! <a href='/rango/about'>About </a>")
```

or change it to use triple quotes.

```
def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("""Rango says hello world! <a href='/rango/about'> 
    About </a>""")
```

Comment: That's not enough information to help. The full traceback will tell you *where* the `NameError` occurred. Note that you need to fix your strings in the views, see my updated answer.